# Collider2D collision not working in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

## Question: Why isn't this code working from inside the power up script ?

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {


        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("I got power up");


            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }




    }
```

## So I have two game objects.

## Triple_Shot_Powerup and Player

When these two collide nothing is happening...idk why

[image]

Player has:

Tag:Player

Box Collider 2D with Trigger True

and Has a Rigid Body

[image]

Triple_Shot_Powerup has:

Box Collider 2D with Trigger True

and Has a Rigid Body

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rigidbody Simulated Checkbox must be True

Answer (score 0):

You dont need rigid body on both objects. if you have rigid body attached to both object make sure your rigidbody Checkbox must be checked